# audio manipulation in mac programming

Tags: objective-c, macos, audio

I'm trying to learn how to do some simple audio manipulation in a program (i'll be writing said program for Mac OS X), such as changing the pitch or speed of a song. I've read that OpenAL is something i'd want to look at and work with. But i've also read that Core Audio is useful. I'm not sure what the difference between the two is or how to use either of them in a program. Any guidance/learning tools would be greatly appreciated.